# Populating input text field in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have loaded the following html page in a **WKWebView** controlled by a specific view controller. **After** the view is loaded I would like that the App automatically populates an input text field in the page.

In this example I would like the app to write "Hello Result" in the "Result" text field of the form below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
 QR Result <input type="text" name="Result" width="20">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code where I load the **HTML page as file** within the view controller:

```
   var htmlFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("apptest", ofType: "html")
        var contents = NSString(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        self.webView?.loadHTMLString(contents!, baseURL: nil)
```

It doesn't matter how I load the view (file or URL). What I want to be able to do is to fill the field at some point **after** loading the view.

Answer (score 7):

The wkwebview/swift equivalent for Uttam Sinha's answer would be.

```
    webview.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('result').value = 'Hello Result';", completionHandler: { (res, error) -> Void in
        //Here you can check for results if needed (res) or whether the execution was successful (error)
    })
```

The WKWebView's version is nicer since it will provide error feedback in case of problems executing your JS.

Answer (score 4):

I have added id attribute in textfield -

```
<form>
 QR Result <input type="text" id="result" name="Result" width="20"/>
</form>
```

In Swift -

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {        
        self.wbView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('result').value = 'Hello Result';")
    }
```

Check screenshot -

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to provide the example in swift?

Comment: Hello, sorry but this one works for UIWebView and not WKWebView.. thanks anyway :)

Comment: Oh equivalent for stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString is evaluateJavaScript in WKWebView. Check whether this works or not.