# Alternate ways to autofill textfield using javascript?

Tags: javascript, swift, wkwebview, autofill

I'm trying to autofill a `username/password` field on a website using `javascript`, however using `.value` doesn't work for this particular page. The text is filled in, but the website reports `username/password` empty as if there wasn't any data. Safari autofill will also often have trouble on the iPhone, however chrome handles it perfectly so clearly there is a way.

I'm using `WkWebView` within swift and evaluating javascript to try to autofill the data.

Here is the website if this helps: login.usfca.edu/login/login

Code I've tried:

```
document.getElementById('username').value='TestUsername';
document.getElementById('password').value='TestPassword';
```

Comment: show what code you tried - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You may want to use `autocomplete` on your HTML

Comment: @TusharWalzade  I added code I've tried. Can you elaborate more or provide a link to what you mean about using autocomplete on my html? I'm quite new to programming. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populating input text field in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29561611/populating-input-text-field-in-wkwebview)

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Use this Code for Autofill**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Prefill inputs</title>
</head>

<body><p>Example Enter Apple...</p>
 Enter: <input id="main" class="input_1" list="competition" type="text" name="competition">
  <datalist id="competition" class="listos">
    <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
  </datalist>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    const $main = $('#main');
    const $inputs = $('.sub');

    const values = {
      trigger: 'community shield',
      communityShield: ['one', 'two', 'three']
    };

    $main.on('keyup input', function () {
      const inputValue = this.value.toLowerCase()
      if (inputValue === values.trigger) {
        $inputs.each(function (i, el) {
          el.value = values.communityShield[i];
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note: I'm not a swift programmer but considering that you use a plain HTML to write your scripts. ***If, in case you aren't using a plain HTML, just inspect your element to get `id` of the same, so that you could ensure that you refer the correct `id`s***.

- **It's necessary to provide an `id` to inputs if you want to assign values using `getElementById`**.

Demonstration -

```js
document.getElementById('username').value='TestUsername';
document.getElementById('password').value='TestPassword';
```

```html
<form action="#" autocomplete="on">
  username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br><br>
  password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Where, `autocomplete` **optional**ly provides you the cached suggestions from the browser while filling inputs.